# Is it possible to have sub-modules in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have this code

```
module M where

a = 1
b = 2
x = 10
y = 20
```

...but as the module grows it's difficult to deal with duplicate names.

Is it possible to have namespaces like this?

```
module M where
  module A where
    a = 1
    b = 2

  module X where
    x = 10
    y = 20
```

..and then

```
...
import M

s = A.a + X.y
```

Comment: What is wrong with `module A.B where`?

Comment: See also [backpack](http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/10/try-backpack-ghc-backpack/), a work in progress in bleeding-edge GHC.

Comment: I have a module which defines a few records and, in order to avoid name collisions, I thought I could group the records in sub-modules

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you proposed isn't currently supported in Haskell AFAIK. That said, nothing's stopping you from creating seemingly namespaced modules. For example:

```
module Top where

myTopFunc :: a -> Int
myTopFunc _ = 1
```

and in another file:

```
module Top.Sub where

mySubFunc :: a -> String
mySubFunc _ = "Haskell"
```

In addition to this, you have a few more tricks up your sleeves to arrange your modules. If you import a module A into B, you can export A's visible entities from B as if they were its own. Subsequently, on importing B, you'll be able to use those functions/datatypes etc. being oblivious to where they originally came from. An example of this using the modules from above would be:

```
module Top (
  myTopFunc,
  TS.mySubFunc
  ) where

import qualified Top.Sub as TS

myTopFunc :: a -> Int
myTopFunc _ = 1
```

Now you can use both functions just by importing `Top`.

```
import Top (myTopFunc, mySubFunc)
```

Comment: The second example is the closest translation I can think of the for the original pseuo-Haskell. `M` becomes `M.Core` or the like, `A`/`B` -> `M.A`/`M.B` and a new module `M` simply re-exports all the definitions.

Answer (score 5):

There are hierarchical module *names*. You can have modules named `M` and `M.A` and `M.X`, but modules themselves don't nest, and `M` is unrelated to `M.A` as far as the language is concerned.

If you want `M` to export everything `M.A` and `M.X` export, you have to do this explicitly:

```
module M (module M.A, module M.X) where
import M.A
import M.X
-- rest of M
```

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot.  But your comment mentions you're just looking for a way to avoid naming collisions.  For this, you can use the `{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}` extension and the compiler will allow duplicate record field names.

Comment: I know of this extension but it doesn't work if I'm generating Lens for my records with makeLenses

Comment: @vidi Yeah I was looking for the same thing when I stumbled across it and your question simultaneously. And indeed, it's pretty limited. It looks like PureScript has way better support for regular record-type stuff; as a newbie to Haskell implementing a web service, I think I might investigate PureScript some more.